# Verifying that a button is visible or not Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a test script which basically steps through a number of steps for different users.  Some users will see a specific button whereas others will not.

I created a method that checks whether or not the button is displayed with the following:

```
public boolean check_create_new_item_button_visible(){

    Boolean visible = driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Item")).isDisplayed();
    return visible;
}
```

and is called in the following way:

```
boolean visible = npc.check_create_new_item_button_visible();
```

But I always get the error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"New Item"}
```

Which is what you would expect as the button isnt visible.

Is probably a stupid error but how do I just get it find out whether the button is on screen or not so that my program can continue?

Incidently,  I moved the code to a part of the program where the button is visible and the boolean visible returns true.  So the code works if the button is visible.

Comment: can you share your `html`

Comment: Sorry @NarendraRajput I couldnt figure out how to paste the html code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `driver.findElement` returns the element if found or throws `NoSuchElementException` if the element wasn't found. To avoid the exception you can use `findElements` and check if the returned list has elements, and if it does check if the first one is visible

```
public boolean check_create_new_item_button_visible() {
    List<WebElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.linkText("New Item"));
    if (buttons.size() > 0 && buttons.get(0).isDisplayed())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @Guy I tried out your code and it works! I learnt something today and for that many thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean check_create_new_item_button_visible(){
  try {
    boolean btnPresence = driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Item")).isDisplayed();
    boolean btnEnable = driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Item")).isEnabled();
    if (btnPresence ==true && btnEnable ==true)
    {
  // click on the search button
      WebElement btn = driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Item"));
      btn .click();
     }
   catch (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e){
            return false;
      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks also @Samir007 I tried your code but it didnt quite work so I modified it as follows to get it working.  I like your solution also.  Thanks!: `public boolean check_create_new_item_button_visible(){try{
 WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.linkText("New Item"));
 if(button.isDisplayed()){
  return true;
 }
  }catch(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException e){
   System.out.println("Element not found");
   return false;
  }return false;}`

Comment: Thanks @tarquin do you want me to update my code? its working so I think it good